# Make Network.Wreq.Proxy from Network.HTTP.Proxy.Proxy

Tags: haskell, networking, proxy

[Network.HTTP.Proxy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.3.3/docs/Network-HTTP-Proxy.html) has a nice function called `fetchProxy`:

```
fetchProxy :: Bool -> IO Proxy
```

> fetchProxy flg gets the local proxy settings and parse the string into
>   a Proxy value. If you want to be informed of ill-formed proxy
>   configuration strings, supply True for flg. Proxy settings are sourced
>   from the HTTP_PROXY environment variable [...]

I want to use the `Proxy` obtained this way with `Wreq` library, which has it's own `Proxy` [defined like this](https://github.com/bos/wreq/blob/master/Network/Wreq.hs#L165), by importing it from HTTP:

```
import Network.HTTP.Client.Internal (Proxy(..), Response)
```

There appears to be a type mismatch between `Network.HTTP.Proxy.Proxy` and `Network.Wreq.Proxy`, where I presume they must be identical.

I import both like this:

```
import           Network.Wreq
import           Network.HTTP.Proxy (fetchProxy)
```

How can I use HTTP.Proxy.Proxy with Wreq and why does GHC see them as different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the Wreq authors were just unaware of the other `Proxy` as they seem to be storing equivalent information. It'll be tricky to get them to talk to each other, however, since `fetchProxy` stores the host:port as a string and Wreq's `Proxy` wants the individual host and port. You'll have to do some URI parsing:

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Text.Strict.Lens
import Network.HTTP.Proxy
import Network.Wreq
import URI.ByteString

main :: IO ()
main = do
  Network.HTTP.Proxy.Proxy host _ <- fetchProxy True
  case parseURI strictURIParserOptions (host ^. packed . re utf8) of
    Left e -> do
      putStrLn "uh oh"
      print e
    Right uri ->
      case ( uri ^? uriAuthorityL . _Just . authorityHostL . hostBSL
           , uri ^? uriAuthorityL . _Just . authorityPortL . _Just . portNumberL) of
        (Just host_, Just port_) -> do
          let opts = defaults & proxy ?~ httpProxy host_ port_
          response <- getWith opts "http://example.com"
          print response
        _ ->
          putStrLn "uh oh"
```

I'm using `lens` here to do the boring bits and pieces of packing/unpacking strings, encoding UTF8, and talking to the `uri-bytestring` package to get URI parsing. But the general idea is that datatypes in Haskell can be sliced and diced simply by pattern matching on the constructor; once extracted, the `host:string` here is funneled down into the `httpProxy` call, which returns Wreq's `Proxy` type. By qualifying the name of the constructor (`Newtork.HTTP.Proxy.Proxy`) I've let the compiler know which module I want that name from.

It would also not be too difficult, and probably less code to boot, to manually parse proxy information from the environment variables yourself. You could even have a separate environment variable for host and port, which would obviate the need for URI parsing. URIs are have such massively low entropy that they're an awful format for storing configuration information.

Comment: Thanks, that is ugly, yet works. I ended up using HTTP.Conduit instead, as it supports SSL tunnelling.